# Does it increase security if the CBC chunks of a AES-256 encrypted bytestream are uploaded to different clouds?

Tags: aes, cbc

I want to backup my data according to the 3-2-1 rule. I already backup to 2 different drives (2 different systems) at home.  In addition i would like to use cloud storage (Google, Amazon etc.). Considering the future weakening of cryptography by advancements in computing power (e.g. key guessing by quantum computing) i want my data to be as safe as possible because once it's uploaded it's prone to decryption in the future (i can't guarantee the data is deleted if i delete it from the cloud(s)).

Does it increase securtiy of my data if i split the CBC chunks to let's say 2 clouds?
Uploading the even numbered CBC elements to e.g. Google and the odd numbered elements to Amazon.
Since one storage hoster is constantly missing the next part of the CBC-Chain (1/2 in total) shouldn't this increase security of the data even if the AES key is known by the hoster(s)?